# How many ways can x-y=z with bounds?

Tags: number-theory

I have $x - y = z$ where $z$ is known and I have arbitrary bounds on $x$ and $y$ (lowest and highest possible value for each).

Is there a way, without resorting to brute force, to determine how many possible ways $x-y$ can equal $z$ given the bounds of $x$ and $y$ and known $z$?

Comment: Did you state your problem correctly? It is trivial to solve as stated.

Comment: Unless I am interpreting my own words improperly, it is stated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming bounds $x_\min\le x\le x_\max$ and $y_\min\le y\le y_\max$, then $x=y+z$ implies $y_\min+z\le x\le y_\max+z$, and combining these you get
$$ \max(x_\min,y_\min+z)\le x\le\min(x_\max,y_\max+z)$$
which can happen in
$$1+\min(x_\max,y_\max+z)-\max(x_\min,y_\min+z)$$
ways. If this is negative, the correct answer is zero.